# How to convert a nullable datetime value to string using data reader?

Tags: c#, datetime, dbnull, idatareader

I'm reading back a `nullable datetime` using the `IDataReader` interface. So far my previous column reads are working as expected.

Except for this column `["Implementation End Timestamp"]` where I try to read back a nullable date time, convert it to string and assign it to a string property named `Implementation_End_String`.

So this is what I tried. First Reading back the `DateTime?` value checking for null then attempting a convert toString() if not null.

But this assignment isn't allowed due to their being "no explicit conversion between string and DateTime?":

```
Implementation_End_String = dataReader["Implementation End Timestamp"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader["Implementation End Timestamp"]).ToString("d-MMMM-yyyy"), //show full month name
```

*I think I need to get the `value` of the DateTime to call toString() on it.*

Question:

How can I convert the read back `DateTime?` value to a string type?

Comment: If the field is supposed to contain a DateTime why do you want to convert it to a string and then back to a DateTime?

Comment: No `Implementation_End_String ` is a string property, I want to convert the read back `["Implementation End Timestamp"]`date to a string representation in short month format. Then assign it to the string variable  If that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `Nullable<T>` type has `GetValueOrDefault` method. You can use this method to retrieve value or default value of `T` (in your case it would be `DateTime.MinValue`) if there is no value. This method will return plain `DateTime` object so you can invoke any `ToString()` methods on it.

Comment: As I said - it's good to read the docs! `GetValueOrDefault` returns default value of type `T` so in your case it would be date 01/01/0001 00:00:00 as this is default `DateTime` value. Therefore you should not check if it is not null, but if it is not `DateTime.MinValue`. Sorry for the confusion! I updated answer in case someone would Google this question :-)

Answer (score 3):

[`IDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) is a quite old interface, thus does not support natively nullable types. If you tend to use it at many places in your code, you'd better create some helpers which will significantly reduce your code. For instance, here are the helper methods for `DateTime?`, you could easily do similar for the other types:

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static DateTime? GetNullableDateTime(this IDataReader source, string name)
    {
        return source.GetNullableDateTime(source.GetOrdinal(name));
    }
    public static DateTime? GetNullableDateTime(this IDataReader source, int i)
    {
        return !source.IsDBNull(i) ? source.GetDateTime(i) : (DateTime?)null;
    }
}
```

This, in combination with the [C#6 null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) would make the task in question simple as that:

```
Implementation_End_String = dataReader
    .GetNullableDateTime("Implementation End Timestamp")?.ToString("d-MMMM-yyyy") ?? "";
```

Comment: Good idea, didn't you mean `.Value.ToString("d-MMMM-yyyy") ?? "",` to string though?

Comment: Although using .value before toString, gives `"Nullable object must have a value."` error. I did also try `?.ToString("d-MMMM-yyyy") ?? "",` but get a syntax error on that assignment.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be `.Value`. If you are getting syntax error, then you probably are not using VS2015 (note the C#6 in the answer).